# SQLAlchemy "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables named `users` and `permissions` and I wanted to create a relationship between them using a table named `userPermissions`. here's how my code looks like:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(Text)
    last_name = Column(Text, nullable=True)

class Permission(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'permissions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(64))
    allow_anonymous = Column(Boolean)

class UserPermission(Base):
    __table__ = 'userPermissions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    permission_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('permissions.id'))
    value = Column(Boolean)
```

I know I might be doing relationships incorrectly but looking through docs and searching, I couldn't find what it is. When I try to create the tables using `db.Base.metadata.create_all(db.engine)` it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /path/project/out.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/project/out.py", line 1, in <module>
    from components.database import setup
  File "/path/project/components/database/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    class UserPermission(Base):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 65, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 116, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 144, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._setup_table()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 481, in _setup_table
    if not table.c.contains_column(c):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your `UserPermission` class, you are using the wrong dunder attribute:

```
__table__ = 'userPermissions'
```

Should be:

```
__tablename__ = 'userPermissions'
```

Sqlalchemy is trying to treat the string `'userPermissions'` as a `Table` object.

Regarding the difference between `__table__` and `__tablename__`, most cases will only require declaring `__tablename__ = "stringvalue"` on a declarative class. It signals that the object should reference a table of that name, and SQLAlchemy can handle the construction of that `Table` object internally.

Declaring a `__table__` on the object instead signals to SQLAlchemy that you want to take control of the construction of the `Table` that the ORM class represents. This would be most useful if you already have a reference to the table from some other means like table reflection. More reading [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html?highlight=__table__#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table).

Answer (score 3):

```py
class UserPermission(Base):
    __table__ = 'userPermissions'
```

here should be :

```py
class UserPermission(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'userPermissions'
```